# How to put database data into a recycler view using a custom adapter?

Tags: java, android

So I implemented [this](https://gist.github.com/quanturium/46541c81aae2a916e31d) adapter as suggested [here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+nickmowen/posts/XgPq8GYFAN2) and now I am just having trouble making that work with my recycler view adapter. Here is the java code for that:

```
public class RVAdapter extends CursorRecyclerAdapter<RVAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    CursorAdapter mCursorAdapter;
    Context mContext;
    //Cursor cursor;
    //public Cursor mCursor;
    MainInfo mainInfo;
    ManagerDatabaseAdapter.ManagerHelper managerHelper;
    public ManagerDatabaseAdapter managerDatabaseAdapter;
   // public List<MainInfo> mainInfoList = Collections.emptyList();

    public RVAdapter (Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);

    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, Cursor cursor) {

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        //return mainInfoList.size();
        return 0;
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView Title;

         MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            Title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Row_Header);
            //Body = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.Row_Footer);
        }
    }
}
```

I am not sure of how I need to change RVAdapter to work with the adapter. Thanks!

Comment: check this will help you http://javatechig.com/android/android-recyclerview-example
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidRecyclerView/article.html